# What should I name my pivot table which contains a two word table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot, naming-conventions

I would like to use Laravel 5.0 many to many relationship and as we know the naming convention is alphabetically joining the two table names... But what if one of the tables is a two word name itself?

For example we have "sub_categories" and "products" tables.

Should the pivot table name be: "product_sub_category"?

---

And yes I know that we can specify the table name as the second argument when we specify our relationship in our models: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'table_pivot');`

But I wanna know if there's a naming convention for this too! So that we can simply leave the second argument and follow the standard conventions...

Comment: I think it's up to you. In this instance, note that 'Subcategory' is a word in its own right!

Comment: Nope, it's important to know what is the right thing to do... Because when I use `belongsToMany()` relationship in my Models then, the Laravel framework itself will look forward the right table and the right column names itself... Of course I can also pass my table name and custom column names as an argument to the method: `belongsToMany('App\Product', 'table_name', 'column1', 'column2')` But I'd like to know what is the convention for this... As it's something that happens so often!

Answer (score 2):

You can name as you want, and specify the table name as the 2nd param on the relationship call in your models:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Model', 'table_name');
```

[Official Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But I know that! I just like to know what is the convention for this(if there's one!) without needing me to specify the table name as the second argument...

Comment: `pivot table name is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names`
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many